# Setting background color to achartengine graph view

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using Achartengine for my application as chart generation tool, I am not able to change the main background view of the chart though the theme is sel as "light holo" (ICS) still it gets black when I add the GraphicalView to the linear layout. The attached image can be helpful.

[image]

I have tried changing the layout color programmatically still no success.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that using `renderer.setMarginsColor(color);`

Comment: @Dan can we make the margin color to transparent, so it shows the background color??

Comment: If you want a transparent background try: `setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01));`